# Neovim with compiledb cant find standard library header file <stdio.h> and <string.h> "clang pp_file_not_found" but no problem whatsoever on its own

Tags: neovim, mason, stm32cubemx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jrqc.png)

(NOTE: I also use the COC.nvim alongside other plugins such as mason and treesitter. )

I was writing codes for the main.c file for STM32L432KC microcontroller and tried to include the standard library files, when i noticed this error on neovim. There isn't any error on the Make-Compilation. I used the "compiledb make" command to generate the compile_commands.json file, so that Neovim is able to find the path to the necessary drivers files automatically generated by STM32CubeMX and it worked fine (the autocompletion etc.), just not with the standard library. And when i edit any .c file without the compile_commands.json, suddenly neovim remembers where to find all the standard libraries and the completion display all the syntax of the functions like usual.

I have looked around but didn't find anything I could use. I found almost similar problems, but the person either solved it without giving any details or the case isn't exactly applicable to mine (or I'm just clueless)